# QPython console error in Bluestacks emulator

Tags: python, bluestacks, qpython, qpython3

I have installed QPython on my android bluestacks emulator. When I launch the console, I get the following error:

```
u0_a56@klte:/ $ /data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/bin/qpython.sh "/storage/sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/.run/.last_tmp.py" && exit
/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/bin/qpython.sh[3]: /data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/bin/python: not executable: magic 7F45
```

I've installed QPython on my android phone where console works fine . 
What could be the cause of this issue ?

Comment: Have you set the path of your python executable in PATH variable?

Comment: No, I have not done that. I've never dealt with PATH variables, can you please write the command ?